# chemfig: crossing reactions like crosswords for species in more than on reaction: definearrow1{plus}{+} stays invisible

Tags: arrows, chemfig, chemistry

Is it possible to `\definearrow` to just put a + sign ?

I would like to cross reactions, to draw this chemical pathway (whose source code is at bottom of this question):

[image]

I have overlapped plus signs over invisible links, and I wonder if there are better solutions.

Here is a smaller example where I used overlaps:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{2em}
\setdoublesep{.3em}
\definearrow1{p}{+}
\begin{document}
%   \schemedebug{true} % for debugging only
    \schemestart
A \arrow(--DPPH){p}[,0.3] \llap{+ }
\chemfig{DPPH^o}\arrow{<=>[1][2]}
DPPHH\rlap{ +}\arrow{p}[,0.3]
\chemfig{*6(=(-CH=[::90]CH-[::90]COOH)-=(-OCH3)-(-OH)=(^o\kern2mm)-)} \arrow(--cc){<->}[-90,0.7]
C \arrow(--AO){p}[180,0.3]
longC\rlap{ +} \arrow(--HH){->[4]}[180]
HH  \arrow{p}[-90,0.1]
\chemfig{\mathop{DPPH^o}\limits^{\mathop+\limits_{\,}}}  \arrow{<=>[5][6]}[-90]
\chemfig{\mathop{DPPHH}\limits_{\mathop+\limits^{\,}}}\arrow{p}[-90,0.1]
Hp \arrow{p}[,0.3]
\llap{ +}\chemfig{DPPH^o} \arrow{->[7]}
DPPHH + OO
% ramifications.
\arrow(@AO--){p}[-90,0.1] \chemfig{\mathop{DPPH^o}\limits^{\mathop+\limits_{\,}}} \arrow{->[3]}[-90] aduit
\arrow(@DPPH--){->[8]}[-90] DPPHH
       \schemestop
\end{document}
```

which gives that:

[image]

I used invisible arrows also used on [chemfig: vertical alignment of coefficient](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347885)
Is it possible to `\definearrow` to just put a + sign ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{2em}
\setdoublesep{.3em}
% \definearrow1{0}{+} % implicite ...
\begin{document}
\def\AO#1#2#3#4{\chemfig{*6(=(-=[::#160]-[::#260]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(-O#3)=#4-)}}
\def\AOAO#1#2#3{\chemfig{*6(=(-=[::60]-[::-60]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(-O#1)=(-*6(-=(-=[::60]-[::-60]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(-O#2)=))-)}}
%   \schemedebug{true} % for debugging only
    \schemestart
DPPHH \arrow{<-[*{0}8]}[-90]
\chemfig{DPPH^o}\rlap{ +} \arrow{0}[,0.3]
\AO{}-H{} \arrow{<=>[*{0}1][*{0}2]}
DPPHH\rlap{ +}\arrow{0}[,0.3]
\AO{}-{^o}{} \arrow(--cc){<->}[-90,0.7]
\AO{}-H{(^o\kern2mm)}  \arrow{0}[180,0.3]
\AO{}-H{(^o\kern2mm)}\rlap{ +} \arrow(AO--AOAO){0}[180]% blank, see below.
\AOAO{H}H{}  \arrow{0}[-90,0.1]
\chemfig{\mathop{DPPH^o}\limits^{\mathop+\limits_{\,}}}  \arrow{<=>[*{0}5][*{0}6]}[-90]
\chemfig{\mathop{DPPHH}\limits_{\mathop+\limits^{\,}}}\arrow{0}[-90,0.1]
\AOAO{^o}{H}- \arrow{0}[,0.3] \arrow{0}[-90,0.6]% le second arrow de cette ligne pour faire de la place l'aduit.
\llap{ +}\chemfig{DPPH^o} \arrow{->[*{0}7]}
DPPHH\rlap{ +}\arrow{0}[90,0.6]\arrow{0}[,0.9] % le premier arrow de cette ligne pour faire de la place l'aduit.
\chemfig{*6(=(-=[::60]-[::-60]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(=O)-(=*6(-=(-=[::60]-[::-60]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(=O)-))-)}
%
% ramifications
% aduit
\arrow(@AO--){0}[-90,0.1] \chemfig{\mathop{DPPH^o}\limits^{\mathop+\limits_{\,}}} \arrow{->[*{0}3]}[-90]
\AO-{}H{(-DPPH)}
% autoruction:
       % to have displayed above the arrow, don't use \arrow(AO--AOAO){->[][*{0}4]}[180]
\arrow(@AOAO--@AO){<-[\strut][*{0}4]}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, I am not satisfied of the placement of "4" in fourth arrow of my complete example, but this is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `\definearrow` a `+` sign: the following simple modification of the example in Section 10.1 of the [Chemfig manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) achieves this:

```
\makeatletter
\definearrow{2}{p}{%
    \expandafter\path\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)
    node[midway, anchor=center]{+};
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}{+}{\CF@arrow@start@node}{#2}{0.5}{-}{\CF@arrow@end@node}
}
\makeatother
```

You can use it like this:

```
\arrow{p}
```

It draws an invisible arrow, and places a node with a `+` sign in the middle. For some reason, naming the arrow `+` gave errors, so I named it `p`. The code also allows you to place labels on top and below the + sign, in case you might want to do that. Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{2em}
\setdoublesep{.3em}

\makeatletter
\definearrow{2}{p}{%
    \expandafter\path\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)
    node[midway, anchor=center]{+};
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}{+}{\CF@arrow@start@node}{#2}{0.5}{-}{\CF@arrow@end@node}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \def\AO#1#2#3#4{\chemfig{*6(=(-=[::#160]-[::#260]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(-O#3)=#4-)}}
    \def\AOAO#1#2#3{\chemfig{*6(=(-=[::60]-[::-60]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(-O#1)=(-*6(-=(-=[::60]-[::-60]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(-O#2)=))-)}}
    %   \schemedebug{true} % for debugging only
    \schemestart
    DPPHH \arrow{<-[*{0}8]}[-90]
    \chemfig{DPPH^o} \arrow{p}[,0.3]
    \AO{}-H{} \arrow{<=>[*{0}1][*{0}2]}
    DPPHH\arrow{p}[,0.3]
    \AO{}-{^o}{} \arrow(--cc){<->}[-90,0.7]
    \AO{}-H{(^o\kern2mm)}  \arrow{0}[180,0.3]
    \AO{}-H{(^o\kern2mm)} \arrow(AO--AOAO){0}[180]% blank, see below.
    \AOAO{H}H{}  \arrow{p}[-90,0.3]
    \chemfig{DPPH^o}  \arrow{<=>[*{0}5][*{0}6]}[-90]
    \chemfig{DPPHH}\arrow{p}[-90,0.3]
    \AOAO{^o}{H}- \arrow(AOAO2.340--){p}[,0.3] % le second arrow de cette ligne pour faire de la place l'aduit.
    \chemfig{DPPH^o} \arrow{->[*{0}7]}
    DPPHH\arrow{p}[,0.9] % le premier arrow de cette ligne pour faire de la place l'aduit.
    \chemfig{*6(=(-=[::60]-[::-60]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(=O)-(=*6(-=(-=[::60]-[::-60]COOH)-=(-O-[::60])-(=O)-))-)}
    %
    % ramifications
    % aduit
    \arrow(@AO--){p}[-90,0.3] \chemfig{DPPH^o} \arrow{->[*{0}3]}[-90]
    \AO-{}H{(-DPPH)}
    % autoruction:
    % to have displayed above the arrow, don't use \arrow(AO--AOAO){->[][*{0}4]}[180]
    \arrow(@AOAO--@AO){<-[\strut][*{0}4]}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked very well! I just edited your answer to use `\arrow{p}` in two vertical reactions, which made ugly \mathop and \limits no more necessary.

Comment: @user2987828 True, I missed those! I also fixed the line where you comment "% le second arrow de cette ligne pour faire de la place l'aduit". Instead of drawing two invisible arrows, you can use anchors to make your arrow start at a different point of your compound. The statement  `\arrow(AOAO2.340--){p}[,0.3]` draws an arrow that does not start at the middle of the right boundary of your compound, but at a point below that. The number 340 is an angle measured in degrees w.r.t the horizontal line, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199827/150114 .